# Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string - Symfony/PHP

Tags: php, symfony

When i submit my form it shows me this error:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string").

[image: Full message Error]

I don't know what i'm doing wrong , this is my code ( PHP )

```
   ->add('purchasedate', DateType::class, array(
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'html5' => false,
            'label' => 'Date d’achat (JJ/MM/AAAA)*',
          ))
```

Purchase Date:

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="purchasedate", type="date")
 * @Assert\Range(
 *      min = "2019-01-14",
 *      max = "2019-04-14"
 * )
 * 
 * 
 * @Serializer\SerializedName("purchasedate")
 * @Serializer\Expose()
 * 
 */

private $purchasedate;
```

[image: Get and Set Method]

**Solution**

I was trying to display the date in a twig template is where the error showed up. I only update the display code

```
{{ user.purchasedate|date('d-m-Y') }}
```

Comment: What is the type of `purchasedate` property of underlying entity object? Full exception message would be helpful too.

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: can you show your get and set method.

Comment: Check the question , i updated

Comment: change annotations of getters and setters to date instead of string

Comment: It's a twig exception so it's not about form submission, but about displaying provided data. In some place you get `DateTime` object while you think it's `string`.

Comment: I answer my question , thanks for the help guys

Comment: i show you the error , no excuses

Answer (score 17, accepted):

just add twig filter to your date

```
{{ mydate |date('d-m-Y') }}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
->add('purchasedate', DateType::class, array(
    'widget' => 'single_text',
    'html5' => false,
    'label' => 'Date d’achat (JJ/MM/AAAA)*',
    'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
));
```

if not

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat(format, db_date);

$date = $date->format('d/m/Y');
```

Comment: I'm worried about something else :(